# How to retrieve `Parcelable` data from an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, parcelable

Can anyone tell me how ca I retrieve `Parcelable` data from 
`intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO);`. the documentation says it returns `Parcelable` but i do not know how to retrieve and process `Parcelable` data?

Comment: according to the doc, it returns a `WifiInfo`, so just cast it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the Parcelable object into WifiInfo :

```
WifiInfo info = (WifiInfo)intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO);
```